# Json into HTML Uncaught Error

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm trying to use a Json database to read a large amount of data into a html document using jQuery. The code I'm using now is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $.getJSON("http://mtgjson.com/json/BNG.json",
        function(data){
            console.log(data);
                $.each(data.cards, function(i,card){
                    content += '<p>' + card.name + '</p>';
                    content += '<p>' + card.rarity + '</p>';
                    content += '<p>' + card.manaCost + '</p>';
                    content += '<p>' + card.type + '</p>';
                    content += '<br/>';
                $(content).appendTo("#content");
                });
            });
});
```

The code seems to work because it returns the data I requested (name, rarity, manacost and type) it doesn't show it in the div named #content. It shows the data only in an error message in the DOM.

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLDivElement]<p>Acolyte's Reward</p><p>Uncommon</p><p>{1}{W}</p><p>Instant</p><br/>
```

I think it has something to do with appending the $(content) to ("#content"), but I'm really new to Json so I can't for the life of me figure it out.

And yes, I have a div named #content in my html before someone asks. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Console log data as requested:

```
Object {name: "Born of the Gods", code: "BNG", releaseDate: "2014-02-07", border: "black", type: "expansion"…}
block: "Theros"
booster: Array[16]
border: "black"
cards: Array[165]
code: "BNG"
name: "Born of the Gods"
releaseDate: "2014-02-07"
type: "expansion"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: post your `console.log(data);`

Comment: Added. The array in wich the needed data is stored is 'cards'.

Comment: is the error message shown in web page or in console? if in console, which line of your code is indicated to have error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a local variable, looks like `content` is referring to some element

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.getJSON("http://mtgjson.com/json/BNG.json",    function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.cards, function (i, card) {
            var content = '<p>' + card.name + '</p>';
            content += '<p>' + card.rarity + '</p>';
            content += '<p>' + card.manaCost + '</p>';
            content += '<p>' + card.type + '</p>';
            content += '<br/>';
            $(content).appendTo("#content");
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ffQhv/)

In your case you have an object with id `content`, so the global variable `content` refers to that dom element. This causes the string concatenation to result in wrong value

Comment: @RGraham yes it is... look at the element to which it is appended